# How to list Amharic (Unicode) code points in python 3.6

Tags: python, utf-8

I want a list containing Amharic alphabet from utf-8. The character ranges are from U+1200 to U+1399. I am using windows 8. I encountered `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-5: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`.

I tried this:
`[print(c) for c in u'U1399']`

How can i list the characters?

Comment: What you've pasted here is a completely different syntax error than the one you're asking about—there's an unclosed `'`, and there are no Unicode escapes anywhere.

Comment: As a guess, you're confusing `\u` and `\U`. The first one takes 4 hex digits, the second one takes 8 hex digits. So you can use `\u1200` or `\U00001200`, but `\U1200` will try to treat the next 4 characters as 4 more digits, which will be an error.

Comment: Your edited version still doesn't have any Unicode escape sequences in it, and now doesn't produce any errors at all.

Comment: As a side note, using a list comprehension for side effects like printing, and ignoring the results, is very misleading and not idiomatic. Just use a `for` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the characters from U-1200 to U-1399, I would use a `for` loop with an `int` control variable. It's easy enough to convert numbers to characters using `chr()`.

The integer value 0x1200 (i.e. 1200 in hexadecimal) can be converted to the Unicode codepoint U-1200 like so: `chr(0x1200) == '\u1200'`.

Similarly for 0x1201, 0x1202, ... 0x1399.

Note that we use `.isprintable()` to filter out code some of the useless entries.

```
print(' '.join(chr(x) for x in range(0x1200, 0x139A) if chr(x).isprintable()))
```

or

```
for x in range(0x1200, 0x139A):
    if chr(x).isprintable():
        print(hex(x), chr(x))
```

<sub>Note that the code samples require Python3.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Can you please explain what `0x1200` mean? I know it represents the unicode characters, but what do the numbers mean?I also prefer a list containing all characters as output, instead of print each separately.

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer. I hope that it helped.

Comment: It did, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I will add an alternative answer for future reference.

The OP wanted to print the Amharic letters using the Unicode range U+1200 to U+1399, and answers provided base their solutions on the Unicode range U+1200..U+1399. This range includes two Unicode blocks including punctuation, numerals, unassigned codepoints, and letters not used in Amharic. Basically the provided solutions include a lot of characters that are not Amharic letters.

The Common Locale Data Repository contains information on character usage for various locales (exemplar data). This includes main exemplars , ie letters needed for this language/locale. Auxiliary exemplars, additional letters that may be used for foreign words or loan words. And index exemplars. This data is accessible via **icu4c** and **PyICU**:

```py
import icu
# Create a LocaleData object for the Amharic Locale
# Use a locale label (string) rather than a Locale object.
ld = icu.LocaleData('am')
# Generate a Unicode Set containing the main (standard) exemplars.
exemplars = ld.getExemplarSet(icu.ULocaleDataExemplarSetType.ES_STANDARD)
# Typecast the UnicodeSet object to a list
exemplars_list = list(exemplars)
# Print list
print(*exemplars_list, sep=" ")
```

or string it all together:

```py
exemplars_list = list(icu.LocaleData('am').getExemplarSet(icu.ULocaleDataExemplarSetType.ES_STANDARD))
```

Answer (score -1):

Your posted code doesn't produce any errors at all:

```
>>> [print(c) for c in u'U1399']
U
1
3
9
9
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

It also doesn't have any non-ASCII characters in it.

You probably wanted to use a Unicode backslash escape. And your problem is probably more like this:

```
>>> u'\U1399'
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-5: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

The reason is that—as the error message implies—a `\U` escape requires 8 hex digits, and you've only provided 4. So:

```
>>> u'\U00001399'
'᎙'
```

But there's a different escape, sequence `\u` (notice the lowercase `u`), which takes only 4 digits:

```
>>> u'\u1399'
'᎙'
```

If you're using Python 2.7, and possibly even with Python 3 on Windows, you may not see that nice output, but instead something with backslash escapes in it. But if you `print` that string, you will see the right character.

The full details for `\U` and `\u` escapes (and other escapes) are documented in [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (make sure to switch to the Python version you're actually using, because the details can be different, especially between 2.x and 3.x), but usually you don't need to know much more than explained above.